# React Native Fragment View

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am doing stack navigation in React Native. It works fine, but the problem is that I want to do the navigation like the fragment navigation in Android.

In the image from link given below, the red highlighted part only gets navigated when I click the arrow button in green highlighted part(The green highlighted part is a navigation header).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa4lL.png

Comment: I think you need collapsible region. https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly... you want to make a fragment in RN. In react native, it called modal and there is many packages providing this. One of this good packages is [react-native-modalbox](https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox).

I hope i understand your question correctly.